# how to reduce the TRIS and FACES from a Displace modifyier

Tags: baking, displacement

i made a billboard from an image texture but the problem is that i was following the Blender gurus texture tutorial using photoshop but the Displace modifier adds 3.3 Million tris , quads and verts , this hangs my pc significantly , so how can i reduce these things , can a bake help

Comment: it depends on the sort of mesh and on what you want at the end, the Decimate modifier / Planar mode can do a nice job, or the Remesh modifier or Remesh tool, etc... you also have an addon called Instant Remesh

Comment: actually the fact is that the displace modifier isn't bringing anything special to my table , its a side object in my Isometric Room Art , so shouldn't i just remove it

Comment: if it's a very rectangular object, maybe try some tools like X > Limited Dissolve, or Ctrl E > Unsubdivide, or as I said Decimate modifier/ Planar mode

Comment: @SHikhaMittal please add pictures to the question, so that someone else but you can know what kind of shape you are dealing with and what settings you are using for the modifiers.